Why is my PC with RJ45 Ethernet connected to router can't ping to other devices that connected the same router via Wi-Fi?
My PC is connected to my router Fiberhome HG6245D using an RJ45 Ethernet connection, the IP of my PC is 192.168.1.2
My other devices are connected to the same router (Fiberhome HG6245D) via Wi-Fi and they're:
ID  SSID        MAC             IP ADD
1   MAA_INWI    ae:x:c3:95:x:8b 192.168.1.13
2   MAA_INWI    96:x:66:c0:x:d6 192.168.1.16
3   MAA_INWI    a4:x:b0:f7:x:2a 192.168.1.18
4   MAA_INWI    6e:x:74:cf:x:f7 192.168.1.17
5   MAA_INWI    8e:x:4d:df:x:8b 192.168.1.23
6   MAA_INWI    e0:x:d0:13:x:f1 192.168.1.9
7   MAA_INWI    90:x:5d:be:x:d2 192.168.1.3

All devices connected to the router via Wi-Fi are able to ping each other, and I can transfer files between them. However, my PC, which is connected to the same router via an RJ45 cable instead of Wi-Fi, cannot communicate or transfer files to the other devices.
Any solution for this, I don't know where I should look for Windows 11 or my router settings.

Do you have some sort of WiFi isolation / WiFi guest network enabled in the router? If so that's expected.

@ChanganAuto Thank you so much for your answer. My router, the Fiberhome HG6245D, is pretty basic. After searching through all the options, I couldn't find anything like WiFi isolation or a guest WiFi option.

BTW, check that the other devices are set to reply to ping, and the router allows it: https://superuser.com/questions/310393/stopping-ping-requests-on-my-home-router

Can your PC ping the router / gateway itself?

@M_D yes, I've just checked it
